# is there any latest compression lib in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, compression

Has anyone worked with the video compression lib?
We're trying to compress the video but not able to compress fast way... it's taking too much of time.
If you have any suggestions or feedback about it, please do let us know.
Thanks!!

Comment: You are not really clear, what you mean by compressing a video? You mean zipping it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

****https://pub.dev/packages/light_compressor
this is for size compression**

[video file size compressor](https://pub.dev/packages/light_compressor)

Comment: yes it is for video cmpression in flutter....!

Comment: this light compressor is not working properly with flutter